# JUnit тестирование пограничных условий метода

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Провожу тестирование java метода с помощью JUnit. Метод принимает строку и возвращает изменённую строку. Протестировал работу метода, на null, на пустую строку. Как проверить на большую и малую строки? Что такое для теста большая и мала строки?

```
public String reverse(String text) {

String[] textFragments = text.split(" ");
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < textFragments.length; i++) {
    char[] chars = textFragments[i].toCharArray();

    int leftElementIndex = 0;
    int rightElementIndex = textFragments[i].length() - 1;

    while (leftElementIndex < rightElementIndex) {

    boolean isLeftLetter = Character.isLetter(chars[leftElementIndex]);
    boolean isRightLetter = Character.isLetter(chars[rightElementIndex]);

    if (isLeftLetter && isRightLetter) {
        swap(chars, leftElementIndex, rightElementIndex);
        leftElementIndex++;
        rightElementIndex--;
    } else {         
        leftElementIndex = (!isLeftLetter) ? ++leftElementIndex : leftElementIndex;
        rightElementIndex = (!isRightLetter) ? --rightElementIndex : rightElementIndex;
    }
    }
    stringBuilder.append(new String(chars));

    if (i != (textFragments.length - 1)) {
    stringBuilder.append(" ");
    }
}
return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: вообще, на тестируемый метод смотреть надо и под него уже граничные условия подбирать.

Comment: добавил тестируемый метод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас несколько неправильный подход к выбору метрик для тестирования. Их надо не брать с потолка, а смотреть конкретно на код метода, построчно, и думать, что в нем может пойти не так.

```
String[] textFragments = text.split(" ");
```

1.1) text == null

1.2) text пустой

1.3) text не содержит пробелов

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

2) тестировать нечего

```
for (int i = 0; i < textFragments.length; i++) {
```

3) тестировать нечего

```
char[] chars = textFragments[i].toCharArray();
```

4) тестировать нечего

```
int rightElementIndex = textFragments[i].length() - 1;
while (leftElementIndex < rightElementIndex) {
```

5) Цикл не будет исполняться в двух случаях, если в `textFragments[i]` есть только один элемент либо он пуст. Соответственно нужно проверить корректность результата для двух этих случаев, например `test = "qwe rty    uio p  d"` плюс 1.2

и т.д.